# Can't do outdoor training for 150km and only on trainer. Can anyone give tips and training plan?

Tags: training, trainer, long-distance, indoor

I just found out that I cannot train outdoors for the next two months for the 150 km I was planning to attempt in the first week of September. Now I am planning to buy the In'ride 100 trainer from btwin as that's what my budget allows me to buy. Will I still be able to prepare for the 150km on the trainer. What are the advantages and disadvantages?  Can anyone give me a training plan and tips. Thanks.

Comment: How long have you been riding?  How far can you ride *now*?  With a 150km ride only two months away, I'd hope you can at least to 50-60 km with no problems, else you're going to have a very difficult time working up to 150 km in that short of a time.  The more details you can provide for your experience on a bicycle and your current fitness level, the better help you'll get.  And I hope you have a good TV plan of some type - you're going to **need** it given all the time you're going to be riding on that trainer...

Comment: @Andrew Henle I can do 60km but with a little problems. The first 40 km I can ride with an avg pace of 24 kmph but the last 20 km drops to around 15 kmph. I have been riding only for the past two weeks with a total of 8 rides so far.

Comment: For sure you CAN train for it indoor.  Whether you should or not is a different question.  Indoor trainers are best for short hard interval sessions where the changes in intensity and the pain take the mind off the boredom.  Trying to do endurance rides on the indoor trainer (i've done a few) are mentally horrible.

Comment: If you have only been riding for two weeks, and your longest rides are 50-60 km, if you don't already have a really good endurance-activity base of fitness - such as being a long-distance runner or cross-country skier - you are going to have a really, really hard time working up to 150 km in just two months.  If you're staring to fade at 40 km, you have to work up to almost four times as far.  And how hilly will the 150 km ride be?  There's a huge difference between a flat 150 km and 150 km with "just" 3,000 m of climbing.

Answer (score 5):

Should be possible, but you are going to need *a lot* of dedication to sitting for hours on the trainer. You'll also need to put a trainer specific or cheap disposable tire on you bike as trainers wear rear tires fast.

The training you need to do depends on what your level of fitness is, the max distance you can currently ride and the nature of the 180km event (flat or lots of hills) and how you want to ride it (target average speed, how long you plan to take overall, number of stops etc.)

It will be easy to search for and build a training plan with 30-60 minute sessions 3-4 times a week that will increase your overall fitness and strength substantially. This should be your initial priority.

The difficulty will replicating the duration and nature of the long ride. I would not try to replicate the distance of the ride on the trainer, but instead the duration and intensity. Estimate the time duration you will take for the event and plan sessions on the trainer working up to about 75% of that, at your planned intensity.

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly a duplicate of [Training for 150 km race in 2 months practicality and plan](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/55667/training-for-150-km-race-in-2-months-practicality-and-plan) , so you can still follow the advice in those answers to good effect.

There are some advantages with a trainer because you can control the effort you make on the indoor trainer, and target specific goals with more structure. There are lots of training plans published online. If you use a heart rate (HR) monitor you can set some personalised HR zones and spend time in specific zones to train endurance, power etc. separately as you wish

You can still do shorter, intense rides during the week and longer, steady rides at the weekend, building the distances up week by week like you would have outside.

Tip: using a specific indoor trainer tyre on the trainer because it will not be damaged by the extra heat. Don't then use that indoor tyre outside!

Disadvantages, you need to buy extra stuff and indoor riding can get boring and hot (no airflow). Resistance to pedalling is pretty linear, so estimating speed or distance is not representative of outside, but you can see how well you ride in week one, and build up time, speed, distance week by week.

Comment: +1 GCN suggests fans and lots of them to help simulate riding outside (in that airflow cools you down outside)